# User stats. Logging IPs and timestamp of visits: how to calculate stats

Tags: php, mysql

I built a API which is used by a app to fetch data from a mySql dB. A part from retreiving the queried data, when a user launches the app, the app sends to the dB the IP of the user and the timestamp when connection was made. This means that I have a table thats similar to this

```
|    IP Number    |   timestamp   |
-----------------------------------
| 193.12.143.145 |   1502020875   |
| 121.144.98.201 |   1499606040   |
| 188.34.12.167  |   1500142980   |
-----------------------------------
```

I would like to draw a chart (or at least have the correct data to draw it) that shows the number of users (Y) by date/time (X). In practice a tipical web stats such a this:

[image]

I'm using PHP. How shoud I treat the data from the dB? What kind of calculation should I do? Should I `GROUP` IPs?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Your example shows a chart showing one count per day. My answer shows how to get that. Do you want the user count to be by hour? Do you want a count of distinct IP values?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) usercount, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) day
   FROM table
  GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
```

It will report in local time, unless you do this:

```
 SET timezone = 'UTC'
```

Comment: I tried your query but it does not divide the IPs by date/time. I would like to know how many IPs connected at a certain date/time. Can this be done using mySQL or should I work it out using PHP?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *divide the IPs by date/time*. Please edit your question to clarify, and maybe give an example.